# AppX package installed, but not accessible

Tags: powershell, windows-11, windows-store-app

Installed AppX package via `Add-AppxPackage`, and it appears as installed when I use `Get-AppxPackage`, but it doesn't appear in the settings or start menu as an installed app, so it's effectively unusable.

```
Name              : Microsoft.ScreenSketch
Publisher         : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture      : X64
ResourceId        :
Version           : 11.2310.54.0
PackageFullName   : Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2310.54.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2310.54.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PublisherId       : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
NonRemovable      : False
Dependencies      : {Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.8_8.2310.30001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                    Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.3_3000.934.1904.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                    Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.32530.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
                    Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.32530.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe...}
IsPartiallyStaged : False
SignatureKind     : Store
Status            : Ok
```

My issue does not stem from looking up the incorrect name of the app. It is not present on the list in settings at all.

Comment: Screen Sketch was renamed to Snip & Sketch over 2 years ago.

Comment: Look instead for Snip and see if it comes up.